# Error loading font file: data/calibri.fnt

Tags: fonts, libgdx

I get this error when I try to load the font file.

`Error loading font file: data/calibri.fnt`

I may be missing something that is very simple (and stupid), but have been trying to figure it out since many hours in SO and googgling.
Here is my sample code -

`import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
 font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal ("data/calibri_new.fnt"), true);
 font.draw(textBatcher, "abcd", 40, 40);`

I have copied calibri.fnt file under the folder data. (I'm not using calibri.png). Can someone please help?

The default font Arial with font size 15 works well when I just keep it to
`font = new BitmapFont();`

Error reads as below - (My reputation is not high enough to post an image :( )

`Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading font file: data/calibri_new.fnt
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.<init>(BitmapFont.java:971)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:120)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:113)
    at com.kilobolt.GameWorld.GameRenderer.<init>(GameRenderer.java:81)
    at com.kilobolt.Screens.GameScreen.<init>(GameScreen.java:38)
    at com.kilobolt.ZombieBird.ZBGame.create(ZBGame.java:13)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Invalid font file: data/calibri_new.fnt
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.<init>(BitmapFont.java:809)
    ... 7 more`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up calibri.fnt in Eclipse (or any text editor). You should notice:

- It is a text file only (meaning it lacks the bitmaps required for a BitmapFont)
- It references a file (`file="calibri.png"`) that needs to be in the same directory

A fnt file mostly just identifies the rectangles in a png file that correspond to each letter.

Copy the png file in too.

Comment: Thanks Chase! I copied my png file into the folder. However the error still persists. Here is the line of code I'm using `font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/calibri_new.fnt"),true);` The error log has the error that I have mentioned in the subject line. I also find a log that says Invalid font file: data/calibri_new.fnt  . Can anyone kindly help!

Comment: Where did you get the files or how are you generating them? Can you post them or the link to them?

Comment: I'm using Bitmap font generator from angel code. Downloaded from here [link](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/). I first adjusted my font style and saved as .fnt file. This automatically generated a .png for me. I have placed both of them in my /data file. I'm also attaching a screenshot of error to my question.

Comment: What is the second (`common`) line in your fnt file look like?

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem because I was using xml generated fnt, libgdx can only handle text fnt.

Also here's the code for creating font:

```
BitmapFont font;
font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/font.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("fonts/font.png"), false);
```

Make sure you have both the png and the fnt in the folder.